# How to resolve the issue of POI not being able to retrieve automatically generated heading numbers in Word?

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to resolve the issue of POI not being able to retrieve automatically generated heading numbers in Word?
e.g.The automatically generated Chinese heading numbers '一' are converted to Arabic numerals '1' after parsing with POI. How can I maintain their original format?

I want to modify the source code, but I don't have the ability.

Comment: Apache POI is open source, so you absolutely have the ability to modify the source code! See https://poi.apache.org/devel/subversion.html for the various ways to download or checkout a copy